# Mysql database making it flexible

Tags: mysql, database-design, create-table

im fairly new to databases etc....I need to build a database using MySql.....that will be flexible.....Ie: I need a basic databse....but dependant upon the user it needs to be flexible to carter for different type of info put in.... So one user may only input data for a small report and another may have to put a lot more in as the report needs to be more detailed.....
The problem I have is that no two reports are the same and to pre-empt every scenarios is almost impossible.
Any ideas anyone??

Thanks

Comment: Your question is to vague. Please try it for yourself and come back when you have some code to show us.

Comment: Also it's probably better suited for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can create a users table, a reports table, a data table, and a reports_data table.

It will look something like this:

```
 _______
|users  |
|-------|
|user_id|
---------

 _________
|reports  |
|-------  |
|report_id|
|user_id  |
 ----------

_______
|data   |
|-------|
|data_id|
---------

________________
|reports_data   |
|-------        |
|reports_data_id|
|report_id      |
|data_id        |
|user_id        |
-----------------
```

Then every piece of data that a user creates for a report you store in the data table, and then store the report_id and all the data_id's in the reports_data table.

Comment: Brill....thanks will have a look at that